# How to find the index value of a variable in SPSS Python

Tags: python, variables, indexing, dataset, spss

Is there a way to find the index of a variable in SPSS Python?

For example, if one of my variables in the SPSS dataset is `ID`
usually, I would be able to access the variable with the following code:

```
varObj = datasetObj.varlist[0]
```

Assuming that `ID` is the first column in my dataset.

But what if the variable `ID` is lost somewhere in the middle of a dataset?
Is there a way for me to find the index value of the variable `ID`?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation of the Variable Class](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_22.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.python.help/spss/programmability_option/python_package_variable.htm), you can get a reference to the variable by name *or* by index:

```
# Create a Variable object, specifying the variable by name
varObj = datasetObj.varlist['bdate']
# Create a Variable object, specifying the variable by index
varObj = datasetObj.varlist[3]
```

So in your case:

```
varObj = datasetObj.varlist['ID']
```

You can, if needed, get the index of the variable by its name, [using the `index` property](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_22.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.python.help/spss/programmability_option/python_package_variable_index.htm):

```
varIndex = datasetObj.varlist['ID'].index
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That last bit solved my problem and put a huge smile on my face. I was looking for the answer for a long time but was so frustrated that I wasn't able to find it. Thank you!

Comment: Cheers. Bookmark that Documentation site, it will most likely be very helpful if you're doing a lot of python/SPSS programming :)

Answer (score 1):

Note also that you can use the spssaux.VariableDict class to get and set (except for type) all the properties of variables.

Also, all the doc for the programmability apis is available under Help > Programmability, and you may find the Programming and Data Management book (pdf) downloadable from the SPSS Community (old) or new Predictive Analytics website at https://developer.ibm.com/predictiveanalytics/